# StringLength Attribute Not validating why my implementation

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I have used [This](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) to do my own implementation of data validation using attributes. However, when I run the unit test it fails

Unit test:

```
      [TestMethod]
      public void CheckAttributes_StringLengthAttribute_ShouldAddErrorIfToManyCharacters()
      {
           //Arrange
           _model.FirstName = "asdf";
           _model.LastName = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

           //Act
           _abstractModelValidation.CheckMyAttributes(_model);

           //Assert
           Assert.IsFalse(_abstractModelValidation.IsValid);
      }
```

just FYI `_abstractModelValidation.IsValid` =  `Errors.Any();`

My implementation of the above link:

```
      protected void CheckAttributes(T model)
      {
           var context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
           var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

           var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results);
           if (!isValid)
           {
                foreach (var validationResult in results)
                {
                     foreach (var memberName in validationResult.MemberNames)
                     {
                          AddError(memberName, validationResult.ErrorMessage);
                     }
                }
           }
      }
```

The model class:

```
 public class ValidatorModel
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [StringLength(25), Required]
      public string FirstName { get; set; }

      [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 9)]
      public string LastName { get; set; }

 }
```

Just FYI the `[Required]` does add the error

Can someone please tell me what I and doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my issue; I hope this helps someone else!

The issue is that there was another overload that is a boolean property validateAllProperties. Changing that to true, did it!

```
      protected void CheckAttributes(T model)
      {
           var context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
           var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

           var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results, true);
           if (!isValid)
           {
                foreach (var validationResult in results)
                {
                     foreach (var memberName in validationResult.MemberNames)
                     {
                          AddError(memberName, validationResult.ErrorMessage);
                     }
                }
           }
      }
```